# What is the proper way to handle non-event driven tasks with Xlib?

Tags: c, multithreading, xlib, xorg

I am writing a graphical program for Linux, in C, using Xlib.  The problem is simple.
 I have an event, that occurs outside of the Xlib event loop, that needs to be handled and will cause some change to what is displayed to the screen.  In my case, I am trying to make a cursor blink inside of a textbox.  My event loop looks like this:

```
XEvent event;
while(window.loop_running == 1) {
    XNextEvent(window.dis, &event);
    event_handler(&window, &event); // This is a custom function to handle events
}
```

**Solution 1a:**

My first thought was to create a 2nd loop with pthreads.  This 2nd loop could handle the asynchronous event and draw as needed to the screen.  However, Xlib, doesn't play nice with multiple threads.  Even if I used a mutex to block the event_handler() function, during asynchronous drawing in the 2nd loop, I still periodically had crashes from X.  Additionally, if the event loop is not cycled, after about 10 calls from the pthread loop, the program locks up.

**Solution 1b:**

This could be solved by calling XInitThreads() at the start of my program.  However, this causes valgrind to report a memory leak.  It seems that there is some memory allocated that is not freed on exit.  And calls to XCloseDisplay() just hang if I call XInitThreads().  I still haven't figured out how to destroy and clean-up windows in my program, but that might be better saved for a separate question.  Additionally, calling XInitThreads() at the start of my program stops the program from freezing after 10 calls are made from the pthread loop without cycling of the event loop.  However, calls to X start to block after about 10 calls from the pthread loop.  Things briefly resume after the event loop is cycled, such as by mousing over the window.  However, calls quickly start blocking again when in-loop event activity ceases.  Interestingly, I noticed that I could replicate this issue in some other programs such as Bluefish.  If I open Bluefish, start a cursor in the main textbox, and then mouseout, after about 10 seconds the cursor stops blinking.  Clearly this isn't always an issue since things like a video player's display would freeze after some period of no X events being triggered.

**Solution 1c:**

I can stop the window from freezing by using XSendEvent() to cycle the event loop after drawing is completed from the pthread loop.  However, this seems really Hacky.  And I can't guarantee that it will work since I don't know at exactly what point, X will stop listening.  I haven't been able to determine the root cause of this issue.  As I said, it seems to happen after about 10 seconds, but this varies depending on how I change the cycle rate of the blinking cursor.  I'm tempted to guess that it is a function of the actual calls to X being made.  There are approximately 2 per pixel, per redraw.  It has to 1) set the foreground color and 2) draw the pixel from the bitmap buffer to the screen.  Currently, my window only supports a resolution of 640x480.  Of course, I am just guessing that this can be used to determine the failure point since I really don't know the cause.

**Solution 2:**

I can drop all of this and re-implement the event loop by polling the event queue with XEventsQueued(), handling them as they come.  But I'll be honest, I hate this solution.  This is a really hacky solution that will increase the processing power required for this application and increase the the event response latency, since I would want to sleep the thread between polls to prevent just spinning the thread and pegging the CPU core.  I am writing this program with the goal of a fast, stable, and lean program.

Does anyone have a solution?  It's such a simple and fundamental problem, but I have only seen sample applications that use XNextEvent in an event loop.  I haven't found any samples of how to handle out of event loop events.  Thanks for the help.  I am a brand new member to Stack Overflow.  This is my first post.  So I apologize if I make a mistake.

Comment: You should use `poll()` with the fd obtained with `ConnectionNumber()` and the fds your other events comes on. When the X11 fd is "ready", you process the events with `while(XPending()){ XNextEvent(); ... }`. Even then, X11 functions which are of the form request/reply (eg `XQueryTree`) may stall your event loop. The solution is to switch to [xcb](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/) (where you could split those in their request/reply parts). IMHO xcb is just as ugly and not much better than Xlib, but it's the only thing readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User: mosvy

Wrote this comment:

> You should use poll() with the fd obtained with ConnectionNumber() and the fds your other events comes on. When the X11 fd is "ready", you process the events with while(XPending()){ XNextEvent(); ... }. Even then, X11 functions which are of the form request/reply (eg XQueryTree) may stall your event loop. The solution is to switch to xcb (where you could split those in their request/reply parts). IMHO xcb is just as ugly and not much better than Xlib, but it's the only thing readily available.

This works great!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I wish you would have written that as an answer.  I would have accepted it for you.

**EDIT:** Deleted my previous edit because I later discovered that the problem was a mistake elsewhere in my full program.  In fact, the edit was incorrect and the code didn't correctly read in events.

Here is how my event loop looks now.  I'll probably reorganize it, to try to clean it up.  But as a proof of concept, here:

```
// window is a custom struct defined and setup elsewhere in my program
// event_handler() is a custom function elsewhere in my program
window.fd = XConnectionNumber(window.dis);
struct pollfd fds;
fds.fd = window.fd;
fds.events = POLLIN;
int poll_ret;
XEvent event;
while(window.loop_running == 1) {
    poll_ret = poll(&fds, 1, 10);
    if (poll_ret < 0) {
        window.loop_running = 0;
    } else if(poll_ret > 0) {
        while (XPending(window.dis) > 0) {
            XNextEvent(window.dis, &event);
            event_handler(&window, &event);
        }
    }
}
```

I can use poll() to listen for all events using kernel file descriptors, including X events.  The file descriptor for X events is obtained with ConnectionNumber().  I also needed to set it to listen to the file descriptor events of type "POLLIN".  Poll accepts an array of file descriptors.  See the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) for more information on the schema.  When poll() returns, I can check if it timed out or if an event is enqued.  I can then act that accordingly.

I believe this will work for custom events if needed.  To do that, I will probably just need to set up my own file descriptors to interact with.  I'll look into it if needed.

This solution means that I do not need to call XInitThreads() since I am not ever making simultaneous calls to X.